# Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

My analysis professor told us to take the following theorem for granted in order to prove other results, but I would like to see a proof of it, since I think it will be beneficial. Here is the theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem.}$(Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem)

If probability measure $\mu_k$ on $(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^k})$, $k\geq 1$, satisfy $$\mu_{k-1}=\mu_k\psi^{-1}_k, \quad k>1, $$ then there exists on $(\mathbb{R}^\infty, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^\infty})$ a unique probability measure $P$ satisfying $$\mu_k=P\pi^{-1}_k, \quad k\geq 1. $$

I want to point out that, given $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $\pi_k:\mathbb{R}^\infty \mapsto \mathbb{R}^k$ is the natural projection defined by $$\pi_k(x_1, \ldots , x_k, x_{k+1}, \ldots ) =(x_1,\ldots , x_k).$$

Is there a probability book where I can find a proof of this theorem? I have been searching online! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a proof in Section 10 of [these lecture notes that I wrote](http://www.unco.edu/NHS/mathsci/facstaff/Eldredge/6710/6710-lecture-notes.pdf).  I tried to make explicit the role played by the topology, particularly compactness, and the connection with Tychonoff's theorem.

It is also in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*.  I believe also in Folland's *Real Analysis* and Resnick's *Probability Path*.  Basically any graduate-level probability text should have it.

Comment: @NateElderedge Thank you.

Comment: The link is broken.